# Is it possible to use the ternary operator "?" to fill an array list in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, ternary-operator

This is probably a dumb questions. I'm modifying a code developed by someone else. I need to particularize the value of some chars array based on a logic variable `ThreeDim`. I'm trying to do this without success.

```
int         VarNumber  = ThreeDim==1 ? 3 : 2;
const char* VarList [] = ThreeDim==1 ? {"X","Y","Z"} : {"X","Y"};
```

But the compiler is giving me errors like

```
error: expected ‘;’ before ‘}’ token
error: initializer fails to determine size of ‘VarList’
```

`VarList` needs to be a `const char*` due to downstream requirements. And its size should be `VarNumber`. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider using the preprocessor, `#define THREE_DIM`, and then use `#ifdef` to select one or the other code to compile:

```
#define THREE_DIM

#ifdef THREE_DIM
int         VarNumber  = 3;
const char* VarList [] = {"X","Y","Z"};
#else
int         VarNumber  = 2;
const char* VarList [] = {"X","Y"};
#endif
```

Comment: At the end this was the solution I used. The one that presented less syntax issues.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do this with different sized array initializers. However, you can put a conditional expression in the initializer:

```
const char* VarList [] = {"X", "Y", ThreeDim == 1 ? "Z" : nullptr};
```

This will always give you a 3 element array with the last element either "Z" or a null pointer.

Comment: Thanks. It compiles now. Thanks again...
Now, I just have to solve the `SIGSEGV` :(
Legacy code...

Comment: Mind the last null element. Could as well be the cause of the segfault.

Comment: Thanks @vitaut. At the end, I used the solution proposed by @GregHewgill. And compiled with and without the `#define` line, generating different executables for each case. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No, because e.g. `{"X","Y","Z"}` is not an *expression*. It's handled specially by the compiler for variable definitions.

And if you're programming C++ you should be using `std::vector` and `std::string` instead, then it would be *very* simple (but verbose):

```
std::vector<std::string> VarList = ThreeDim==1 ?
    std::vector<std::string>{{"X","Y","Z"}} : 
    std::vector<std::string>{{"X","Y"}};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And agree, the type of object is far from optimal. But as I said, the code is not mine, and I can't change the object type without significant modifications downstream

Answer (score 1):

As per [C11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.7.9, arrays aren't initialized with an expression but with an *initializer list*; these are two different syntactical elements and can't be mixed. This derives from the fact that arrays aren't assignable, and treating one as a value (as opposed to a value that decays to a pointer) therefore doesn't make sense. Since they aren't values, there's no way to create a legal expression that passes around whole arrays.

The closest *direct* analogue to what you're asking for would be:

```
const char** VarList = ThreeDim==1 ? (const char*[]){"X","Y","Z"} : (const char*[]){"X","Y"};
```

...but this comes at the cost of changing the type of `VarList`, and is probably not what you want.

Comment: Nice idea, but [on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/SvxyQ5) this gives "error: taking address of temporary array", which seems about right...?

Comment: @TonyD in C taking the address of a temporary array isn't an error, I guess that's yet another C/++ difference.